# Ajax popup in Selenium

Tags: ajax, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

Is there anyway to capture/record Light Box (Ajax) using

> Selenium IDE

?

Comment: Explain what exactly you want to 'capture'. A quick glance at the JS shows it uses static ID's and classes for it's popup, so yes, it's perfectly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not for sure wheter Selenium IDE capture/record Light Box (Ajax) in the form you expect from it. 
See [image: the screen below]

Selenium IDE is able to capture the fact of the click which causes LightBox appear. But it is difficult to register the time you need to get all  the AJAX from server.
Being QA selenium automation(writing on java) I'd prefer a lil bit another approach.
you can use webDriverWait conditions:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//xpath_to_element")));
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878478/selenium-webdriver-determine-if-element-is-clickable-i-e-not-obscured-by-doj)

Or you can invoke `fluentWait` mechanism:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

this fluent wait method returns you found webElement which you can operate on.
**usage:**

```
String xPathElement ="...blablab.....";
WebElement found  = fluentWait(By.xpath(xPathElement));
found.click();
//found.getText().trim():
```

hope this helps you