# selenium: wait on a webelement

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have this function that finds an element by css selector and waits for it to be clickable:

```
def wait_for_element_clickable(cls, selector, timeout=10, parent=None):
    """ wait for an element to be clickable """
    if parent is None:
      parent = cls.driver
    wd_wait = WebDriverWait(parent, timeout)

    # Wait for it to be visible too.
    cls.wait_for_element(selector=selector, parent=parent)

    wd_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)),
                  'waiting for element to be clickable ' + selector)
    return parent.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
```

Now I have a situation where I already have a WebElement and I just want to wait for it to be clickable. Is there a way to use EC.element_to_be_clickable on an existing WebElement?

Comment: Try with Javascript wait it will handle ur problem

Answer (score 2):

`element_to_be_clickable` doesn't have overloading for WebElement in Python (although it has in Java and C#). However you can write your own

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, driver):
       return element.is_displayed() and element.is_enabled()
```

Uses

```
wd_wait.until(element_to_be_clickable(element))
```

Comment: It looks like element.is_displayed() and element.is_enabled() is not an equivalent replacement for wd_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable which is also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30830689/549226

Comment: I'm still seeing "Element...is not clickable at point..." errors with that code.