# Selenium get elements by location

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to perform a click into an element using SeleniumQuery but every time that I execute the click it says that there is another element at the same location.

Is there any way to get all the elements that are at the same location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver - determine if element is clickable (i.e. not obscured by dojo modal lightbox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878478/selenium-webdriver-determine-if-element-is-clickable-i-e-not-obscured-by-doj)

Comment: did u try using javascript ?

Comment: @Louis the question is not exactly the same, as you can see at the below apart from determine if element is clickable or not I need to check which one is and then click the clickable one.

Comment: @Dileep17 I don't like to inject javascript, but thanks!

Comment: @jordiPons, can you add more details like HTML structure of elements which are displayed @ same location ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never saw any case like this, but I would check if the `element is clickable`([Selenium WebDriver - determine if element is clickable (i.e. not obscured by dojo modal lightbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878478/selenium-webdriver-determine-if-element-is-clickable-i-e-not-obscured-by-doj)) and do the click on the one that is indeed clickable.

So, get the two elements and click the one that is clickable

Answer (score -1):

In order to get all the elements present in the same location we can use `findElements` method of `WebDriver`. Please find the sample code below:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(<locator to identify the elements>));

// You can loop through the available elements using for-each loop
for(String eachEle : allElements) {
     // Write the logic
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Using the browser inspector I can find that there is two elements at the same location but they have different xpaths so this solution won't work for me. Thanks